# Discriminant of a trinomial $x^n+ax^m+b$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, discriminant

I am trying to compute the discriminant of the trinomial $x^n+ax^m+b$.

I have tried using resultants but cannot see how to approach it.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is Theorem 4 in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379584900892):

$$
(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}b^{m-1}(n^{n/d}b^{(n-m)/d}-(-1)^{n/d}(n-m)^{(n-m)/d}m^{m/d}a^{n/d})^d,
 $$
where $d=\gcd(n,m)$.

Comment: Swan's paper mentioned in that paper is freely available [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1103036322)

Answer (score 1):

$$x^n+ax^m+b=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x-\zeta_k) \tag{1}$$
$$ n x^{n-1}+am x^{m-1} = \sum_{h=1}^{k}\prod_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ k\neq h}}(x-\zeta_k)\tag{2}$$
and by evaluating $(2)$ at $x=\zeta_i$ we get:
$$ n\zeta_i^{n}+am \zeta_i^{m} = \zeta_i\prod_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ k\neq i}}(\zeta_i-\zeta_k)\tag{3} $$
or:
$$ (am-an) \zeta_i^{m}-b = \zeta_i\prod_{\substack{1\leq k\leq n \\ k\neq i}}(\zeta_i-\zeta_k)\tag{4} $$
from which:
$$ \prod_{i<j}(\zeta_i-\zeta_j)^2 = \pm\frac{1}{b}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left[(am-an)\zeta_i^m-b\right].\tag{5}$$
If $M$ is the companion matrix of $p(x)=x^n+ax^m+b$, $\{\zeta_i^m\}$ are the eigenvalues of $M^m$, hence the RHS of $(5)$ can be computed from
$$ \det\left((am-an)M^m-bI\right) \tag{6}$$

Comment: But we expect that the discriminant is an expression that depends only on the coefficients and not contains the roots.... or not?

Comment: @EmilioNovati: every symmetric function of the roots can be expressed in terms of the coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: I agree! but I don't understand how we can eliminate the $\zeta_i$ at RHS in your $(5)$

Comment: @EmilioNovati: I added $(6)$, that explains how our discriminant is related with the determinant of a $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: I see! I was searching a way to find the discriminant using, as usual, the resultant of the polynomial and its derivative. But your method seems better (+1).