# Proving a Galois group is not contained in $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-groups

I have been asked to prove that the Galois group for $f(x)=x^4-6x+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is not contained in $A_4$. I have already proven that $f(x)$ is irreducible and that it contains a 3-cycle. How would I go about proving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to @Lord Shark's answer. I suspect that this one is more useful in contrived examples rather than real-life problems. But if you had to produce a polynomial with Galois group $S_{31}$ (say) this might be the way to go.

$f(1)=-3$ and $f(\pm\infty)=\infty$ so $f$ has at least two real roots.

$f'(x)=4x^3-6$ is non-decreasing, so $f$ has exactly two real roots.

Complex conjugation therefore gives a non-trivial element of the Galois group, which acts as a transposition. Hence the Galois group is not in $A_4$.

Comment: I understand but this question is part b) of an old exam paper where part c) is to prove that the Galois group contains a 3-cycle and part d) is to prove that it contains a transposition. Also since the discriminant wasn't explicitly given and it is tough to work out first hand, I don't think that was the method he was looking for either. Is there any other way to work it out?

Comment: All I am supposed to know so far in the question is $f(x)$ and the fact that its irreducible.

Comment: Not all exam questions are fair or sensible, and in previous years the  lecturer may have taught some clever trick that deals with this. Apart from the discriminant and the "exactly two non-real roots" trick, all that comes to mind is to reduce mod p for various primes. Did the course cover that technique? How did you get the 3-cycle?

Comment: Another thought. Were resolvent cubics part of the deal? I think that if you calculate the resolvent cubic you'll get  an irreducible with one real root. This gives that the GG of the quartic can't be even and has a 3-cycle.

Comment: We touched on resolvent cubics in lectures but again it seems like an expensive calculation for an exam. To find the 3-cycle, I considered $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, then considering for all elements of $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ less {0} (as it is clearly not a root) evaluated at $x^4$ give remainder 1, found $x=3$ as a root. So $x^4-1x+2=(x-3)h(x)$ where h is irreducible and degree 3, hence representing a 3-cycle by Dedekinds theorem.

Comment: I think I may have misread your original comment yesterday which I think is actually the answer the examiner was expecting :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

An irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ over $\Bbb Q$ has its
Galois group a subgroup of $A_n$ (in the action on zeros of $f$)
if and only if the discriminant of $f$ is a square of a rational number.

See [Discriminant of a trinomial $x^n+ax^m+b$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1798118/discriminant-of-a-trinomial-xnaxmb) for more about evaluating discriminants of polynomials
with only three terms.